# Android: How to use View's setTag, getTag and findViewWithTag methods?

Tags: android

I'm having some trouble with a section of code for my android app. I keep getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to set the background of an `ImageView` object.

**Here's the code:**

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (view == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) view;
    }
    imageView.setTag(position);
    return imageView;
}

private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        ImageView imageView;
        //Variable i, here, is from a for loop.
        imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewWithTag(i);
        //I get a NullPointerException at the next line, "Log.d"
        Log.d("View 1", imageView.toString());
        //If I get rid of the "Log.d" line above, 
        //the NullPointerException occurs on the next line
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewWithTag(position);

        Log.d("View 2", imageView.toString());
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    };
}
```

I suspect the problem with my code is because of what parameter I'm passing the `setTag()` method and what parameter I'm passing the `findViewWithTag()` method. If someone could show me an example of how to set tags and find views with tags, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

**Edit: Here's the error log. I'm not sure where to put it, so I will put it here.**

```
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.jacksmartie.PhotoMem.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:79)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-04 21:47:24.314: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Comment: @JoxTraex: Here's the error log. I hope it's what you're looking for. I'm not sure where to put it, so I placed it in my original post.

Comment: It seems that my initial approach to implementing a feature in my android app is not the best way to do things. I'm going to post a new question asking how I should approach this problem.

Comment: @JoxTraex, @Tancho: Woohoo! I figured it out! It works! I used `view = parent.getChildAt(i);`. I'm so happy!

Comment: Are u sure you have inflate view by setContentView() or through LayoutInflatore before find the view setontent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line is part of your culprit:

```
com.jacksmartie.PhotoMem.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:79)
```

Put a breakpoint here:

```
Log.d("View 1", imageView.toString());
```

And look what your `imageview` reference object [imageView] is, I'm expecting that it is null because you aren't linking it properly.

If it is null, this means that your link to the reference view is not right. If that's the case, then you need to assign it properly like so:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.Button01);
```

However; since you're using what seems to be a `ListView`, the pulling of that is slightly different. This means that the way you're pulling the view is wrong, do some research, should find something to help clear that up!

Comment: @JoxTraex: Yes, it's `imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`. That's where it always crashes. When I comment out the lines that set background color, it works. I suspect it's because my `findViewWithTag` method isn't returning something that's usable.

Comment: @JoxTraex: I tried putting a breakpoint at the `Log.d` line. The android emulator crashed anyway. I guess I don't know how to set it up properly. I'm still pretty new to programming. You're probably right that I'm not referencing or pulling the view correctly. But I can't use `findViewById` because my `imageViews` use dynamic resources. In other words, I'm scanning the filesystem for images and loading them into my `imageViews`. So, there are no predetermined `R.id's` to use.

Comment: @Jack Smartie , well since it crashed you now know that its something else that is crashing it, make sure your button is properly assigned a click listener.. If you dont then the listener will be null and null cannot be a listener so you'll get an exception.

Comment: @JoxTraex: I think it's the case that I don't know how to set breakpoints correctly or something. I tried moving the breakpoint and it just skips right through it. But the error logs keep saying it's the same line that crashes the program - when I try to reference a view through `findViewWithTag`.

Comment: @JoxTraex: Oops. Sorry, I'm still learning. I ran it in debug mode and it's helpful. I still haven't solved the problem, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: well keep working at it still have a lot to learn, you learn by doing so now you know how to get your application in debug mode! Primarily what you are interested in seeing is what your variables are at runtime at a specific point in time within your app!

Answer (score 4):

Well, you don't say where it's crashing. And it's not clear what you're doing.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    imageView.setTag(position);
    return imageView;
```

Where is `imageView` declared? What's it set to?

```
private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                        ImageView imageView;
                        //Variable i, here, is from a for loop.
                        imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewWithTag(i);
```

You're declaring a second local variable called `imageView` here, but it'll disappear when you exit scope. If you're relying on this for setting your previous `imageView` variable, you'll have no joy. `i` is from a `for` loop, but how does that relate to the `position` in the `getView()` method?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm sorry, I removed some code to make it less cluttered. In the `onItemClick()` function, I have placed comments in `//` that describe where the program is crashing. I'll add back some of the code I removed to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

The nullpointer happens because the imageView variable is null, since findViewById did not find the view, so you should make a check if it is null.
Android Log fails since it cannot print a null variable, instead of setting the tag, try to set the ID by doing:

> imageView.setId(position);

If I understand correctly you do not use the ID in the adapter and since the View is generated it does not have one by default.
The Tag is mostly used to put an object that is needed by the View it self as a helper variable, so use it visely :)

If you explicitly need to use the Tag then check if the View is actually there, meaning check that you are not re-writing the tag somewhere along the way...

Comment: @JoxTraex: Debug mode shows that the view retrieved by findViewById or findViewWithTag is null. I'm not sure why it's null. Is it because I'm not retrieving it with the correct code? Or is it because GridView doesn't allow you to retrieve views other than the one passed to its onItemClick() function?