# How can I add onclicklistener for each cell of a table?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

I have a **TableLayout** with a table. How can I set **onClicklisteners** for **each cell** of this table?

I have not found any proper solution for this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6604243/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to set click listener for every View object incorporating your TableLayout.

Comment: I have a 10x10 table, so 100 cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if you have the table rows:

```
tableRow.setClickable(true);
tableRow.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

Otherwise you need to use `setTag()` and `getTag()` using customAdapter for tableLayout cell. you can get the idea how to use `setTag()/getTag()` in adapter from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890072/android-how-to-use-views-settag-gettag-and-findviewwithtag-methods#5890168).

Inside your adapter you can track:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int row, final int column, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (converView == null) {
        converView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResource(row, column), parent, false);
        if (row == -1){
            converView.setId(column+2);         // assign new id to the cell view
            setHeaderId(column);        // store that view id in the header array
        }  
    }

    converView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               // perform what you want

        }
    });     

    return converView;
}
```

Comment: But how can I identify the cells in a row?